# Flutter error : Got the error on length and map

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

### [image]

I Got the error on length and map after upgrading flutter.
And the same code is running in the old project.
when I print only snapshot.data then data is not showing.

```
class _TabPageState extends State<TabPage> {
  var response;
  var medicineSubCategoryApi;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    fetchData(widget.medicineCatUniqId);
  }

  fetchData(var medicineCatUniqId) async {
    var api = Uri.parse($baseUrl/productSubCatApi.php?a2rTokenKey=$a2rTokenKey&pcat=$medicineCatUniqId');
    response = await http.get(
      api,
    );
    print("medicineCatApiLnk " + api.toString());
    print("medicineCat" + response.body);

    medicineSubCategoryApi = jsonDecode(response.body);

    print("medicineCatString" + medicineSubCategoryApi.toString());
    return medicineSubCategoryApi;
    // setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: FutureBuilder(
          future: fetchData(medicineSubCategoryApi),
          // initialData: medicineSubCategoryApi,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              print(snapshot.data.length.toString());
              print(snapshot.data.toString());
            
              // API data will be stored as snapshot.data
              return DefaultTabController(
                length: snapshot.data.length,
                child: Scaffold(
                  appBar: AppBar(
                    title: const Text('Tabbed AppBar'),
                    bottom: TabBar(
                      isScrollable: true,
                      tabs: snapshot.data
                          .map<Widget>((choice) => Tab(
                                text: choice['psubCatName'],
                                // icon: Icon(choice),
                              ))
                          .toList(),
                    ),
                  ),
                  body: TabBarView(
                    physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                    children: snapshot.data.map<Widget>((choice) {
                      return Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                        child: ChoicePage(
                          choice: choice,
                        ),
                      );
                    }).toList(),
                  ),
                ),
              );
            } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return Text('Error');
            } else {
              return Text('Loading');
            }
          }),
    );
  }
}


class ChoicePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const ChoicePage({Key? key, this.choice}) : super(key: key);
  final choice;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final TextStyle? textStyle = Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4;
    return Card(
      color: Colors.white,
      child: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
           
            Text(
              choice['psubCatName'],
              style: textStyle,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

when I print This thing I got then coming error.

```
class _TabPageState extends State<TabPage> {
  var response;
  var medicineSubCategoryApi;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
// for loading
    fetchData(widget.medicineCatUniqId);
  }

  fetchData(var medicineCatUniqId) async {
    var api = Uri.parse('$baseUrl/productSubCatApi.php?a2rTokenKey=$a2rTokenKey&pcat=$medicineCatUniqId');
    response = await http.get(
      api,
    );
    print("medicineCatApiLnk " + api.toString());
    print("medicineCat" + response.body);

    // in double quotes drink is key value of json

    medicineSubCategoryApi = jsonDecode(response.body);

    print("medicineCatString" + medicineSubCategoryApi.toString());
    return medicineSubCategoryApi;
    // setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: FutureBuilder(
          future: fetchData(medicineSubCategoryApi),
          // initialData: medicineSubCategoryApi,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              print(snapshot.data.length.toString());
              print(snapshot.data.toString());
               return Column(
                 crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                  Text(snapshot.data.length.toString()),
                   Text(snapshot.data.toString()),
                 ],
               );
              // API data will be stored as snapshot.data
              
                    }).toList(),
                  ),
                ),
              );
            } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return Text('Error');
            } else {
              return Text('Loading');
            }
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: please confirm the exact type of snapshot.data. Is it List or Map ?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
print(snapshot.data!.length!.toString());
print(snapshot.data!.toString());
```

it can solve the problem if you were not using Flutter 2.0 before

Comment: @Hasan No it not worked ,See in image Which I updated.

Comment: (snapshot!.data! as List).length try this